# CakePHP 2.2 random notice message

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2

From time to time, randomly and very rarely, I get this message on my CakePHP site:

> Notice (8): session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP) failed: No such file or directory (2) [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php, line 615]

Why is this happening?
I am using sessions all the time since the user gets in so... why do I only get this message from time to time and so rarely?

I am using Windows Server 2003 over IIS 6 but i get the exactly same problem over Windows 7 and IIS 7.

Comment: Do you have a writable C:\WINDOWS\TEMP folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that either there is no `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` directory or it is not writable by the IIS User.
That's why it cant open a new session.

There could also be a dead-lock or write-lock on the disc, but this is highly unlikely. Check the users that are trying to access that folder.

Comment: I will take a look and then I tell you.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, the only permission IUSR is missing and needs to be granted is "List folder" under Advanced Security on the C:\Windows\Temp folder.

[Notice (8): session_start() at CakePHP 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123615/notice-8-session-start-at-cakephp-2-2/15233031#15233031)

If you're on a Windows server it's highly unlikely that C:\Windows\Temp does not exist.